# OpenCart Slideshow Controller Not Showing Images

Tags: php, opencart

Hello I am still trying to get the images from open carts image directory with out using resize. I have done what other people have said but still no image showing.

```
<?php  
class ControllerModuleSlideshow extends Controller {
public function index($data) {
static $module = 0; 
$this->load->model('design/banner');
$data['banners'] = array();
$results = $this->model_design_banner->getBanner('banner_id');
foreach ($results as $result) {
if (is_file(DIR_IMAGE . $result['image'])) {
$data['banners'][] = array(
'title' => $result['title'],
'link'  => $result['link'],
'image'  =>$result['image']
);
}
}
$data['module'] = $module++;        
if (file_exists(DIR_TEMPLATE . $this->config->get('config_template') . '/template/module/slideshow.tpl')) {
return $this->load->view($this->config->get('config_template') . '/template/module/slideshow.tpl', $data);
} else {
return $this->load->view('default/template/module/slideshow.tpl', $data);
}
}
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change:

`'image'  =>$result['image']`

to:

`image'  => "image/".$result['image']`

Have a nice day !!

Comment: Works perfect just what I am after

Answer (score 0):

First Simply you need to pass the banner id if you are manually fetching image

Second you are using `$data['banners']` instead of `$this->data['banners']` which is global variable for controller so you don't need to pass extra parameter in view, you can directly fetch banners via `$banner`

Third you need to render the value at the end so that data will be available on template.

```
<?php  
class ControllerModuleSlideshow extends Controller {
    public function index($data) {
        static $module = 0; 
        $this->load->model('design/banner');
        $data['banners'] = array();
        $results = $this->model_design_banner->getBanner(8);
        foreach ($results as $result) {
            if (is_file(DIR_IMAGE . $result['image'])) {
                $this->data['banners'][] = array(
                    'title' => $result['title'],
                    'link'  => $result['link'],
                    'image'  =>$result['image']
                    );
            }
        }
        $this->data['module'] = $module++; 

        if (file_exists(DIR_TEMPLATE . $this->config->get('config_template') . '/template/module/slideshow.tpl')) {
            $this->template = $this->config->get('config_template') . '/template/module/slideshow.tpl';
        } else {
            $this->template = 'default/template/module/slideshow.tpl';
        }

        $this->render();
    }
} ?>
```